# NodeJS module instances

Tags: node.js

I have the following code. I want to use the prototype keyword as I want to call method functions and not class methods, why does this give me an error? If I remove the prototype call this works. How can I write this code so I'm able to use instances not class methods?

```
//app.js
var MyTest = require('./MyTest')
var myTestInstance = new MyTest()
myTestInstance.testFunction(function(reply){
   console.log(reply)
})

//MyTest.js
module.exports = function() {

   function MyTest() {}

   MyTest.prototype.testFunction = function(cb) {
      cb('hello')
   }

   return MyTest

}
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK myTestInstance.testFunction(function(reply){ ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object.<anonymous>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to have your app.js working as it is you need to replace the content of MyTest.js with the following:

```
function MyTest() {}
MyTest.prototype.testFunction = function(cb) {
  cb('hello');
};
module.exports = MyTest;
```

As you have it in app.js you need a constructor and not a factory function.

Comment: Thank you! That actually helped alot.